# serverless framework and use key management service (KMS)

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, amazon-kms, aws-serverless, google-cloud-kms

Basically I use `serverless` framework [serverless](https://serverless.com/) for a function that allows me to send/receive emails through mailgun.

For this I have a `config.js` file set up in my serverless folder.
This `config.js` contains all my API keys, email address, login, etc for my “mailgun” function.

I want to use Google Cloud KMS to encrypt the resource `config.js`, because I am afraid my senstive data gets stolen and misused. 
The encrypted file is `config.js.enc`. [google_key_management_service](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials#using_the_encrypted_variable_in_build_requests)

But `serverless deploy` does not decrypt my `config.js.enc`. It throws me a resource/syntax error…

Any solutions/ideas how I can make KMS work for my `config.js` file in my `serverless` framework?

I added AWS tags also, because they have a similar KMS as Google Cloud. But actually I think the real issue is with the `serverless` framework and to make encrypted files work in deploying serverless with `sls deploy` command, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: I believe that at the moment the best solution for this is to put wrapped secrets into the config.js and then unwrap them at load time. We're aware of the need for something more useful and are working on solutions. I will ping the documentation people to see if we can put together a description of best practices here.

Answer (score 3):

The serverless framework appears to include native [AWS SSM integrations](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-secrets-api-keys/):

```yaml
functions:
  myfunc:
    # other config
    environment:
      TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${ssm:myFunc}
```

However, as you noted, there's no similar functionality on GCP, so you'll need to roll some of this on your own. You may be interested in some of the strategies outlined in [Secrets in Serverless](https://www.sethvargo.com/secrets-in-serverless/):

### Do you need the secrets?

It's always important to ask - do I actually need these secrets? Could you leverage Cloud Provider IAM (or even [cross-cloud OIDC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc.html)) instead of injecting secrets into my application? Where possible, try to leverage the IAM solution provided by the various clouds. Obviously there are still quite a few cases where a secret is required.

### Encrypted environment variables

Before the function is launched, you encrypt the plaintext secrets locally into ciphertext (encrypted strings). Here's an example with gcloud, but you can also use the API or other tools like [HashiCorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/gcpkms/index.html):

```
$ gcloud kms encrypt \
    --ciphertext-file=- \
    --plaintext-file=/path/to/my/secret \
    --key=my-kms-key \
    --key-ring=my-kms-keyring \
    --location=us-east4 \ 
    | base64
```

This will output a base64-encoded, encrypted string, which you then store in your `config.js`:

```
CiQAePa3VBJLbunLSqIJT+RS4nYiKdIaW6U69Y...
```

On startup, configure your application to:

1. Base64 decode the string
2. Decrypt the ciphertext using Cloud KMS
3. Store the plaintext in-memory for as long as the secret is needed

I'm not sure what language(s) you are using, but here's a nodejs sample. You can find a lot more samples on GitHub at [sethvargo/secrets-in-serverless](https://github.com/sethvargo/secrets-in-serverless):

```node
const cryptoKeyID = process.env.KMS_CRYPTO_KEY_ID;

const kms = require('@google-cloud/kms');
const client = new kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient();

let username;
client.decrypt({
  name: cryptoKeyID,
  ciphertext: process.env.DB_USER,
}).then(res => {
  username = res[0].plaintext.toString().trim();
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});

let password;
client.decrypt({
  name: cryptoKeyID,
  ciphertext: process.env.DB_PASS,
}).then(res => {
  password = res[0].plaintext.toString().trim();
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});

exports.F = (req, res) => {
  res.send(`${username}:${password}`)
}
```

### Google Cloud Storage

Since you're on GCP, another option is to use Google Cloud Storage (GCS) directly to store the secrets. This would remove your coupling from the serverless framework.

1. Make a bucket:

   ```
   $ gsutil mb gs://${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}-serverless-secrets
   ```
2. Make the bucket private:

   ```
   $ gsutil defacl set private gs://${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}-serverless-secrets
   $ gsutil acl set -r private gs://${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}-serverless-secrets
   ```
3. Write some secrets into the bucket. Even though they are being committed as plaintext, they are encrypted at rest, and access is tightly controlled via IAM.

   ```
   $ gsutil -h 'Content-Type: application/json' cp - gs://${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}-serverless-secrets/app1 <<< '{"username":"my-user", "password":"s3cr3t"}'
   ```

Then create a service account which has permission to read from the bucket, and assign that service account to your functions.

Finally, read from the bucket at function start (Python example this time):

```py
import os
import json
from google.cloud import storage

blob = storage.Client() \
    .get_bucket(os.environ['STORAGE_BUCKET']) \
    .get_blob('app1') \
    .download_as_string()

parsed = json.loads(blob)

username = parsed['username']
password = parsed['password']

def F(request):
    return f'{username}:{password}'
```

Comment: brilliant answer! i actually visited your blog prior to coming here, looking forward to reading more from you. about your answer, could you please show me how to "read from the bucket at function start" with nodejs please?

Comment: Sure! In python functions, things that happen outside a `def` (at the top level) are executed when the function boots. Things inside the def are executed when they are called (invoked via a URL, triggered via pubsub, etc). In the example above, the download and decryption of data from GCS happens once at function start*. If you were to move all the code inside the `def F(request)` block, the download and decryption would happen on each invocation of the function.

Comment: * GCF functions can "scale to zero" and can autoscale beyond one instance, so this is a bit of a simplification, but gets the point.